How the EFD system of F18e shows the fuel in tanks of the fighter?
I was seeing this image:

How the EFD system of F-18E/F shows the fuel in the tanks of the fighter? I mean it's very low. e.g. 7.2 lb? Is it rounded?

Fuel qty is displayed in 1000s of pounds. The Fuel Qty Indication System measures fuel quantities from the individual internal and external tanks and displays them on the Engine Fuel Display in 1000s of pounds, corrected for ambient temperature.
The EFS above indicates the jet has 7,200 lbs of internal fuel onboard with a preset bingo fuel state of 4,500 lbs.
